# iOS - Unexpected orientation displayed after invoking presentViewController from subview

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, rotation, orientation

I create 3 controllers:

- RootViewController: a container view-controller contains a sub-view
- SubViewController: a view-controller viewed inside RootViewController via `addSubview`
- OverlayViewController: presented by using `presentViewController` from `SubViewController`

When rotating device, then show OverlayViewController, then dismiss it, RootViewController will be displayed in unexpected orientation (180 degrees rotated)

https://youtu.be/qBujC0bTYts

After one-day doing google and trying many things, I see that if I add a sub view-controller into a view-controller without using `addChildViewController`, it will cause that issue

```
class RootViewController: UIViewController {

    var subViewController: SubViewController?
    @IBOutlet weak var subView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.subViewController =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SubViewController") as? SubViewController
        self.subView.addSubview((self.subViewController?.view)!)
        self.subViewController?.view.frame = self.subView.bounds

        //ADD THIS TO FIX ERROR
        self.addChildViewController(self.subViewController!)
    }
}
```

Would you please help me know why, and how to solve without `addChildViewController`? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found this 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

> To incorporate a child view controller into your content programmatically, create a parent-child relationship between the relevant view controllers by doing the following:
>
> 1. Call the addChildViewController: method of your container view controller. 
>      This method tells UIKit that your container view controller is now managing the view of the child view controller.
> 2. Add the child’s root view to your container’s view hierarchy.
>      Always remember to set the size and position of the child’s frame as part of this process.
> 3. Add any constraints for managing the size and position of the child’s root view.
> 4. Call the didMoveToParentViewController: method of the child view controller.